# Getting a filtered list of objects in django admin from django model.ForeignKey field

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have five models:

```
Class League(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    league = models.ForeignKey(max_length=30)

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    league = models.ForeignKey(Team)

class Fixture(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField();
    league = models.ForeignKey(League)
    team_1 = models.ForeignKey(Team, rel="home")
    team_2 = models.ForeignKey(Team, rel="away")

class Team1_score(models.Model):
    fixture = models.ForiegnKey(Fixture)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    score = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
```

Now in the django admin, when I am editing details about editing Team1_score, I only want to be listed about Players from team 1. This is what I am doing in admin

```
class Team1ScoreInline(models.TabularInline):
    extra = 1

class Fixture(models.Admin):
    inlines = [Team1ScoreInline, Team2ScoreInline]
```

But it lists me a display of all the players in the db when i select a player to add to the score card.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Django 1.3+, you can use queryset option as explained in:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset